# Datatable override function from dataTableExt.oApi

Tags: javascript, datatables

I need help with overriding function in Datatable.js. I need to override _fnEscapeRegex function in Datatable. I tried to write plugin. But it doesn't work.

```
$.extend( $.fn.dataTableExt.oApi, {
_fnEscapeRegex: function ( sVal ) {
 ...
}
```

also tried

```
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnEscapeRegex = function (sVal){...}
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at jQuery DataTables sources, it seems that this function wasn't intended to be overridden. `$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi._fnEscapeRegex` is just a way for plug-in authors to call internal private function `_fnEscapeRegex`.

Your best bet would be to modify the source code instead.

Also note that there is [`search.regex`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/search.regex) option that allows to enable / disable escaping of regular expression characters in the search term if this is what you're after.

Comment: It's also doesn't work . I rechecked, file was included corectrly after Datatable and jquery but it doesn't override .
I replace function directly in Datatable.js ( for test purpose)  in that case it works , but  override doesn't work.

Comment: @ohmyfgod, you're right. I just looked at DataTables source code and it looks like it's not overridable unless you change the source code. I think this is the only way.